# Export PDF to csv using python (tabula)

Tags: python, pdf, tabula-py

When exporting a PDF file to csv, it returns an error:writeheader() takes 1 positional argumentbut 2 were given

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate
import csv

df = read_pdf("asd.pdf")
print(df)


with open('ddd.csv', "w", newline="") as file:
    columns = ['specialty ',"name",'number_of_seats','Total_seats,' "document_type", "concent"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=columns)
    writer.writeheader(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code copied from http://theautomatic.net/2019/05/24/3-ways-to-scrape-tables-from-pdfs-with-python/, there is also more details ...

```
import tabula
 
file = "http://lab.fs.uni-lj.si/lasin/wp/IMIT_files/neural/doc/seminar8.pdf"
 
#tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "all", multiple_tables = True)

# output just the first table in the PDF to a CSV
tabula.convert_into(file, "output.csv", output_format="csv")
 
# output all the tables in the PDF to a CSV
tabula.convert_into(file, "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

Comment: When I run the code it gives an error:build_options() got an unexpected keyword argument 'all'